# Data be duplicated after merging

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use Pandas (In can use VBA but it takes quite a long time) to merge 2 sheets of Excel into 1 (Like Vlookup function in Excel). However after merging, results become duplicated and I don't know why. Below is the code that I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\hoatran\Desktop\Test data.xlsx',sheet_name='Loan')
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\hoatran\Desktop\Test data.xlsx',sheet_name='MD48')
results = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['v_contract_number'],how='left')
results["d_revised_maturity_date"] = pd.to_datetime(results["d_revised_maturity_date"]).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(results)
```

Input data is 14,662 rows but Output data is 15,338 rows.

You can see file [here][1]
[1]: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ClabD4EjWxDbSo3FxyLdGf34czt316OC

Please help me check where I went wrong. Thanks and best regards

Comment: Please provide an [mre], avoid links to data, especially if on a private drive. You can create sample data by using: `df1.iloc[:10].to_dict()`and post that here, same for df2. Try to reduce the data to recreate the problem as short and simple as possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you check if df2 has duplicate keys ?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your notice, I'll pay attention in the next time.

Comment: @AkashDubey Oh yes the data in df2 is duplicated, thank for your advice. So I have to drop duplicate df2 before merging right?

Comment: @hoatran Yes, before you merge, In your case you will have to make sure that the keys in df2 are unique.

Comment: @AkashDubey After dropping, everything work well for me. Thank you so much.
But I have another question, as you see in the df2, I have a colum named Times. I want to merge df1 with df2 on 'v_contract_number' and the smallest number of 'Times'. Can you give a suggestion?

Comment: I am not sure If I completely understand "samllest number of 'Times'"

Comment: @AkashDubey Please check my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 14,662 rows in first sheet and >20,000 rows in 2nd sheet there is a case,  when you are doing left-merge if your right dataframe has multiple elements in with same id it appears multiple time in the resulting data frame. please chec the example for the reference.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'b': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'baz','foo'], 'c': [3, 4,0]})

df1
      a  b
0   foo  1
1   bar  2
df2
      a  c
0   foo  3
1   baz  4
```

merge:-

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='a')

    a    b  c
0   foo  1  3.0
1   foo  1  0.0
2   bar  2  NaN
```

Comment: Thank for your help, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I want to do something as below

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'v_contract_number': ['VN120001438']})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'v_contract_number': ['VN120001438','VN120001438','VN120001438'], 'Times': [13, 10, 8],'d_revised_maturity_date': ['2028-04-28','2028-07-29','2028-06-30']})

# df1
          v_contract_number
        0       VN120001438

# df2
  v_contract_number  Times d_revised_maturity_date
0       VN120001438     13              2028-04-28
1       VN120001438     10              2028-07-29
2       VN120001438      8              2028-06-30

results = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='v_contract_number')
print(results)

# result
  v_contract_number  Times d_revised_maturity_date
0       VN120001438     13              2028-04-28
1       VN120001438     10              2028-07-29
2       VN120001438      8              2028-06-30
```

But my expected output as below:

```
# result
      v_contract_number  d_revised_maturity_date
    0       VN120001438       2028-04-28
```

I just want to keep 'd_revised_maturity_date' of the biggest 'Times'

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This should help : ```results[results.Times == results.Times.max()]```

Comment: @navaneethnanda Yep, I did it as below:
df2 = df2.sort_values(['Times'], ascending=[False])
df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['v_contract_number'],inplace=True,keep="first")

After that, I merge df1 and df2 and Output came as what I want